# How to increase timeout for Axios call [React]

Tags: reactjs, axios

I'm trying to increase the timeout of an axios call. Unfortunately, because I am doing some ffmpeg conversation, it seems the call is timedout before the process can be done. Below are the console lines. where "file has been converted successful" is the completion of the backend process, and you can see /downloadShare is returned before.

Any idea if I'm doing it right? Code block below.

```
GET / 200 0.466 ms - 18
GET / 200 0.392 ms - 18
GET /downloadShare?id=xxxxxx - - ms - -
GET / 200 0.408 ms - 18
GET / 200 0.411 ms - 18
GET /downloadShare?id=xxxxx - - ms - -
GET / 200 0.410 ms - 18
GET / 200 0.395 ms - 18
GET / 200 0.396 ms - 18
GET / 200 0.433 ms - 18
file has been converted successfully
GET / 200 0.672 ms - 18
GET / 200 0.588 ms - 18
GET / 200 0.430 ms - 18
file has been converted succesfully
```

My code

```
const url = `${ConfigMain.getBackendURL()}/downloadShare?id=${id}`;
    return Axios.get(url,{
        timeout:100000
    })
        .then(response => {
            console.log('aaaaa', response);
        return response.data
        })
        .catch(e => {
                return []
        });
```

Comment: You shouldn't rely on that happening in a a single request, see e.g. https://farazdagi.com/posts/2014-10-16-rest-long-running-jobs/ for a better pattern.

Comment: thanks i will be doing this. if you want to put this into an answer I will accept it

Answer (score 0):

To increase axios timeout you can create an axios instance and then set the desired timeout

```
const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: url,
  timeout: '8000ms',
});
```

to make API call you can use created axios instance like this,

```
api.get(url)
```

Comment: However for long running request, you should consider jonrsharpe's comment.